# Laravel Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'field list' (SQL: update `tutorials` set `_token` =

Tags: php, laravel

If i update my Form Model Binding i am getting the above error.
I have already put all my database fields to the fillable field with no affect i am still getting the error.

This is the Form of my edit view

```
{!! Form::model($tutorial, ['route' => ['tutorials.update', $tutorial->id], 'method' => 'PUT' ]) !!}
```

My fillable / guarded fields in my Model

```
 /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable =
    [
        'title',
        'subtitle',
        'content',
        'meta_desc',
        'meta_title',
        'seo_title',
        'tags',
        'slug',
        'updated_at',
        'added_on'
    ];

    protected $guarded = ['id', '_token'];
```

This is my TutorialController

```
public function update(Tutorial $tutorial)
    {

        $input = Input::except('_method'); // Request::all() is not working
        $tutorial->update($input);

        return Redirect::route('tutorials.index')->withSuccess(
            'success.'
        );
    }
```

And last but not least my routes

```
 Route::get('edit/{id}', [
        'as' => 'tutorials.edit',
        'uses' => 'TutorialsController@edit'
    ]);

    Route::put('edit/{id}', [
        'as' => 'tutorials.update',
        'uses' => 'TutorialsController@update'
    ]);
```

Comment: If you set the method to PUT Laravel adds automatically a hidden _method field. Its something about the fillable fields but i dont know why/where

Comment: follow this link for put method.http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form
i think you need to use put in lowercase

Comment: I know how to create a put form - even if i use POST i am still getting the error.

Comment: make all field as fillable using this protected $fillable = array('*'); then remove your protected fillable and guard.then try again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel adds a CSRF protection token called `_token` to your form. You need to remove that from the input as well, otherwise Laravel thinks it is a part of what you want to insert.

```
$input = Input::except('_method', '_token');
```

Then, you should remove the `$guarded` array, because you should have *either* that *or* a `$fillable` one - not both.

The reason you're getting the error is probably because you added the `_token` field to your `$guarded` array - now, Laravel thinks it's a column on your model even though it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I like to use

```
        $inputs = Request::only('field1','field2');
```

For you

```
$inputs = Request::only('title',
    'subtitle',
    'content',
    'meta_desc',
    'meta_title',
    'seo_title',
    'tags',
    'slug',
    'updated_at',
    'added_on');
```

Answer (score 0):

First you assign to a variable Input::all(). Input all is an array. Then You unset the Key _token  and pass assigned variable to update. 
e.g.

```
$input = Input::all();
unset($input['_token']);
Client::where('id', $id)->update($input);
```

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the _method and _token like this

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    product::whereId($id)->update($request->except('_token','_method'));
    return redirect('/product')->with('completed', 'customer has been updated');
}
```